# Default DNS Server not switched after connecting to OpenVPN

Tags: server, 18.04, dns, openvpn, systemd-resolved

I'm using a OpenVPN connection between my laptop and my server. The configuration was working until today (i simply ran `apt update && apt upgrade`), but since then my DNS settings are "wrong" after connecting to the OpenVPN.

After connecting to the OpenVPN Server, i have two "catch all" DNS Domain entries (`DNS Domain: ~.`) in my `systemd-resolve` configuration.

Stripped output of `systemd-resolve --status`:

```
Link 11 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.X.Y
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 2 (enp0s25)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.16.X.Y
                      10.16.X.Y
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Therefore DNS queries now aren't savely tunneled through the VPN but also may be transfered via the normal network.

This leads to a DNSLeak and even worse: VPN-Internal Hostnames aren't resolved correctly (every now and then).

I only know of options to add the `DNS Domain: ~.` entry to the tun0-Interface for resolved. But how do i remove an already existing one from the real interface?

I'm already using this config to update systemd-resolved in my OpenVPN client.conf:

```
# Upate systemd-resolvd
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
```

Anybody got an idea how to solve this?

// Update:
Looks like this is a longer known problem with NetworkManager starting to attach the root DNS Domain to links at random. There is an interesting discussion about it in a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/issues/59) in the repo of the developer of the `update-systemd-resolved` script.

// Probably [this commit](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/ad0400408ef797c75407e3bc016379ff0944aa16) to NetworkManager broke it. Since it introduced the default dns route for all interfaces behavior.

Comment: did you solve it? I'm having the same issue

Comment: The original issue seems to be still pending on Network-Manager. But they even may never fix this.
I just added a script which overwrites the DNS-Settings via the `systemd-resolved --set-domain "XXX" --interface enp0s25` in my Connect-To-Vpn-Script.

Comment: is your script invoking openvpn? would you share it?

Answer (score 2):

Add to the client configuration file (the file with extension .ovpn) downloaded from the OpenVPN server the line:

```
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
```

As you know, before adding this line, in Ubuntu 18.04 you must install `update-systemd-resolved` scripts as described in https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved

If it still does not work, perhaps you must add your internal DNS server too. Check the lines you add at the end of the .ovpn file looks like:

```
script-security 2
dhcp-option DNS 10.1.0.1  # replace this IP with your DNS server IP.
dhcp-option DOMAIN yourinternaldomain.local  # replace this with your internal domain name.
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

---

### If you use the UI (gnome) to connect

Last, if you are using the UI VPN Icons to connect to your VPN, you must re-import the .ovpn modified file.

To do that execute in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install openvpn openvpn-systemd-resolved resolvconf
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Click in Ubuntu start menu:

[image: Ubuntu Menu]

Type the word "network" and click on Network. It should show somthing like:

[image: Network setup]

Click in the "**+**" sign on VPN and click in "import from file" option:

[image: import ovpn file]

Once imported, add a name and click the "add" button at the top right of the dialog.

You are all set!

---

To connect to the VPN, click in the network icon and after that in the lock icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer. But as stated with updates in my original post, this is not an issue of OpenVPN Configuration and/or the `update-systemd-resolved` script. It's just NetworkManager misbehaving by adding the default Route randomly to interfaces. See this discussion: https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/issues/59

Comment: Indeed it is. The fix was not backported to Ubuntu 18.04. Until that is done we will have to deal with workarounds. I hope they fix it in 18.04 soon.

Comment: Actually, this helped me, by enabling resolved config so that it does not fall back to /etc/resolv for DNS lookup was a nice fix after modifying the ```/etc/nsswitch.conf```. I don't have a ton of networking experience but after setting up an OpenVPN client-server the DNS route for some reason would break on a RasPI.