# In Ubuntu 18.04 Default DNS not switching after switching to OpenVPN when used from GUI but works from commandline

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn

I am using Ubuntu 18.04
I followed the instruction in 
[Default DNS Server not switched after connecting to OpenVPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143932/default-dns-server-not-switched-after-connecting-to-openvpn)
and in 
https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved

From the command line when I run the DNS switch does happen but when I try to import using the GUI and turn it on it does not update the DNS.

```
sudo openvpn --config Downloads/aws-tk.ovpn
```

Is there any other setting that needs to done to make it work from the GUI?

content of /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53 
options edns0
```

My .ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 1234
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-nocache
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
cipher AES-256-CBC
reneg-sec 0
mssfix 1420
script-security 2
dhcp-option DNS 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
up-restart
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

Comment: [edit] your question, show us the content of `/etc/resolve.conf`

Comment: updated the comment

Comment: what does your `journal -f` say

Comment: @bac0n could you please elaborate just started in Linux and ubuntu.