# Problem with DNS with OpenVPN on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, vpn

I have installed the OpenVPN server and the Bind9 DNS server on the company server. The part of the server config is below. The important part is a pushing route and DHCP DNS option.

```
local 10.0.9.2
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.0.12.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.0.9.0 255.255.255.0" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.9.2"
```

When connecting on Windows or Elementary OS, everything works great. Only traffic to the server is going through the VPN, the rest does not. If the client is forcing to pass all traffic through the VPN, the internet access works too. In both cases, when trying to access `git.internal.mycompany.org` it gets DNS records from my Bind9 DNS server and connects correctly.

But this does not work in Ubuntu. When passing whole traffic through VPN, a record from DNS is taken. But when only server traffic goes through VPN, then DNS is not reached and I cannot access the git server via URL. When reaching via IP, it works.

I tried also to add to the client config this.

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
```

But this does not help. Maybe because when I try to run the script directly, I got an error `/etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved: řádek 404: dev: unbound variable`.

I don't know how to fix this. I tried to search here on AskUbuntu and others, but most suggest adding up and down to the config. Which does not work for me. It is a problem because most of my colleagues are using Ubuntu. Only few computers are using Windows or other Linux distro.

---

### Update with applied changes

When applied changes from @heynnema, here is what is printed in console https://pastebin.com/DkjHguqE when connecting via terminal. After that, `ping git.internal.mycompany.org` doesn't work.

Another found facts:

- When I added `redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp` into config, then my public IP is IP of the server, but still **cannot** ping URL above.
- When imported config into the UI of Ubuntu as mentioned https://askubuntu.com/a/1188022/972420, ping works until I uncheck `Use this connection only for traffic within this network`.

Comment: It seems like a problem with `systemd` https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems, that the main problem is with `systemd-resolve` as described here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076
Really great article is here, which I took as a starting point: https://www.gabriel.urdhr.fr/2020/03/17/systemd-revolved-dns-configuration-for-vpn/

A small workaround that worked for me is to run this after every connection to VPN. Basically setting DNS manually

```sh
sudo resolvectl dns tun0 10.0.9.2 # Replace with IP of your DNS server
# All internal services are like git.int.mycompany.com or ldap.int.mycompany.com
# You can try to set up "~mycompany.com", worked for me as well
sudo resolvectl domain tun0 "~int.mycompany.com"
```

## How to automate it

**With NetworkManager**:
If you use Network Manager (pictures of Manager available [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188022/972420)), you can automate this with scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`

Create custom script, name it `02-ifupdown` set `chmod +x` to it and paste

```
#!/bin/sh

EXPECTED_VPN_NAME="MyCompany VPN" # Put your VPN name here
VPN_CONN_NAME=`nmcli --get name,type con show --active | grep vpn | sed 's/\:.*//'`

if [ "$2" = "vpn-up" ] && [ "$EXPECTED_VPN_NAME" = "$VPN_CONN_NAME" ]; then
        resolvectl dns tun0 10.0.9.2 # Replace with IP of your DNS server
        resolvectl domain tun0 "~int.mycompany.com"
fi
```

---

**With CLI**:
Create your custom script, set `chmod +x` to it and paste into config:

```
script-security 2
up /path/to/my/script
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing this packages:

> sudo apt install resolvconf openvpn-systemd-resolved

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your client .ovpn mods this way:

From this...

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
```

To this...

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. But this does not work either. I visited several other topics here and nothing helped. I also tried downloading VirtualBox with fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04, configured OpenVPN and this does not work either.

Comment: And I tried to use GUI in Ubuntu and imported OVPN file. Even when I wrote my DNS IP directly into that GUI, it does not work.

Comment: Some changes and updates are added into my original post

Comment: @Arxeiss It's over my head then. Sorry.

Comment: I think this must be bug or something, because I can find similar questions but without any working response. Thank you for trying

Comment: This actually worked for me, I had to install these before: `sudo apt install resolvconf openvpn-systemd-resolved`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this, a list of domains, without quotes (Ubuntu 20.04)

```
...
 resolvectl domain ${TUN} int.example1.com example2.internal
 resolvectl dns ${TUN} 10.127.0.2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).